# Как сделать статическое свойство класса в питоне?

Tags: python, ооп

Пробую так:

```
class ChatCodes:

   _chat = 'cht'

   @property
   def chat(self):
      return self._chat
```

если использую так:

```
print(ChatCodes.chat + 'any_str')
```

то появляется ошибка:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'property' and 'str'

как правильно создать статическое свойство?

Comment: [Это третья ссылка в Гугл](http://python-3.ru/tag/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B%20Python), тут подробно описано и даже скорее всего рассмотрены все возможные ошибки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В принципе, объявленный параметр класса со значением - уже может использоваться как статическое свойство

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     param = "value"
...
>>> MyClass.param
'value'
>>>
```

Это же значение будет доступно и для экземпляра класса. Разве что у экземпляра есть опасность, что значение свойства изменится в процессе работы. Тут стоит позаботиться, чтоб этот параметр не изменялся и/или чтоб обращение к свойству шло исключительно через имя класса, а не экземпляра.

Можно использовать статический метод - объявляется с помощью аннотации `@staticmethod`. Правда и обращаться к нему придётся как к методу, а не свойству

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     @staticmethod
...     def param():
...             return "value"
...
>>> MyClass.param
<function param at 0x04962A30>
>>> MyClass.param()
'value'
>>>
```

Если достаточно ленивой инициализации (то есть обращаться к свойству будем через экземпляр класса), то можно использовать аннотацию `@property`

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     @property
...     def param(self):
...             return "value"
...
>>> MyClass.param
<property object at 0x0474B210>
>>> MyClass.param()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'property' object is not callable
>>>
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.param
'value'
```

Ну и вариант на любителя (на случай, когда значение свойства нужно вычислить):

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def _method_to_create_static_prop():
...             return "value"
...     param = _method_to_create_static_prop()
...     del _method_to_create_static_prop
...
>>> MyClass.param
'value'
>>> MyClass._method_to_create_static_prop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class MyClass has no attribute '_method_to_create_static_prop'
>>>
```

Comment: Значит @property для класса не работает, только для экземпляров. Буду учитывать. Спасибо!

Comment: статическое property не показано в ответе (так чтобы `MyClass.param` вызывало бы функцию)

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите, чтобы `C.class_property` вызывало бы метод класса, можно метакласс `__getattr__` метод определить:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random

class ClassPropertyMeta(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, key):
        if key == 'class_property':
            return cls._get_class_property()
        raise AttributeError(f"<{cls!r}.{key!r}>")

class C(metaclass=ClassPropertyMeta):
    @classmethod
    def _get_class_property(cls):
        return random.random()

print(C.class_property)
# -> 0.333495437410268
```

Аналогично для модулей в Питоне 3.7 ([PEP 562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random


def __getattr__(name):
    print(name)
    return random.random()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import module_attr
    print(module_attr.module_property)
    # -> module_property
    # -> 0.420563286888762
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но если свойств будет много, код будет громоздким или нет? Как на производительности сказываются такие трюки?

Comment: @Александр: без рабочей программы, в которой обращение к свойствам класса является узким местом согласно вашему profiler, о микрооптимизациях бессмысленно говорить.